# How can I find all streaks of non-equal bool elements in list?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, search

I need to find all sequences longer than 2 of non-equal neighbors elements.

I've tried to write my own function that will do it, but unfortunately, I'm missing something, also the code is looking terrible, I hope python already have something that can solve my issue.

```
from itertools import groupby

def zig_zag(l):
    if len(l) < 3:
        return []

    streaks = []
    streak = []
    going = False

    i = 1
    while i < len(l) - 1:
        if l[i] != l[i - 1]:             
            streak.append(l[i - 1])
            streak.append(l[i])
            going = True
        elif l[i] != l[i + 1] and going: 
            streak.append(l[i + 1])
        else:
            streak = []
            streaks.append(streak)
            going = False
        i += 1

    # Check for last elem
    if l[-1] != l[-2] and going:
        streak.append(l[-1])
    if going:
        streaks.append(streak)

    res = []
    for streak in streaks:
        res.append([x[0] for x in groupby(streak)])

    return res
```

## Expecting results:

### Example 1:

`Input: [True, False, True]`

`Output: [[True, False, True]]`

### Example 2:

`Input: [True, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False]`

`Output: [[True, False, True], [True, False, True, False]]`

## Current results:

### Example 1:

`Input: [True, False, True]`

`Output: [[True, False, True]]`

### Example 2:

`Input: [True, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False]`

`Output: [[True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False], [True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False]]`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is Pythonic enough but here is a much simpler way to do this

```
arr = [True, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False]
res = []
start = 0
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    if arr[i] == arr[i-1]:
        if i-start > 2:
            res.append(arr[start:i])
        start = i
if len(arr) - start > 2:
    res.append(arr[start:])
print(res)
```

Outputs: `[[True, False, True], [True, False, True, False]]`
Keep a `start` index where your current sub-array starts. As soon as you find a repeating character figure out if the current subarray has length greater than `2` and reset the `start` position. Notice the corner case at the end.

Comment: Thank you, looks like it works, don't fully understand how it works, but will try to look closer. Still wondering if there some library or built-in for this kind of task.